# How to determine operating system bits (32 vs 64-bit) in elisp

Tags: elisp

I've tried searching around but have come up with nothing: How can I determine the bits (32-bit or 64-bit) of my operating system with elisp?

On my 64-bit Linux machine, `system-configuration` evaluates to `"x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu"`. I don't have a Windows 32-bit machine available, but could I potentially do

```
(defconst 32-bit (not (null (string-match "^i386-.*" system-configuration))))
(defconst 64-bit (not (null (string-match "^x86_64-.*" system-configuration))))
```

to detect the bits?

**Edit:** "Why would you want to know that?" I wanted to write an Elisp script that would download and run the appropriate version of an executable (32 or 64-bit) for the user's OS.

Comment: Wouldn't that only give you what architecture emacs was built on? You could be running a 32 bit emacs binary on a 64 bit system. I would assume the best way to do this would be (case system-type ...) with calls to a os specific tool that can determine architecture.

Comment: As was mentioned in other comments, you may need this for different purposes: to identify the size of the integer you can have in Emacs, to identify what other programs can receive as an input. If Emacs is 32-bit, but runs on a 64-bit machine, then knowing the system parameters won't help you to identify the size of an integer you can use. Also, you could count on integer overflow, say, `(ash 1 31)` to find out whether integers will overflow or not.

Comment: Re' your last edit: I don't think there is a cross-platform way to identify that. You would probably need to write OS-specific code for each case you care about and assume the system is the same as Emacs in other cases.

Comment: There's always /proc/cpuinfo.

Comment: @Qudit No `/proc` on Windows.

Comment: @Jackson Yeah, you'd have to do things differently for each OS.  Or just assume everyone uses Linux (my typical solution to cross platform issues).

Answer (score 3):

This is quite hacky, and I'm not sure how reliable it is, but the value `gc-cons-threshold` depends on the underlying word size. It's `800000` on 64-bit systems, and `400000` on 32-bit systems.

```
(defconst 32-bit (= gc-cons-threshold 400000))
(defconst 64-bit (= gc-cons-threshold 800000))
```

Answer (score 2):

The issue of 64/32 bit is just a part of the problem.  Look at the larger problem: the user may be running Debian on a machine with an ARM processor, for example.  Or she may be running a FreeBSD system.  Also, under Windows, if the downloaded program will want to interact with Emacs, you'll probably want a different version depending on whether your Emacs is a Cygwin or a "native" build.

So, `system-configuration` is probably a good starting point, but you probably want to keep *more* of it than just the 64/32 bit info.  You may actually want to keep the whole of `system-configuration`.

Answer (score 1):

Given the use case (taken from a comment `I wanted to write an Elisp script that would download and run the appropriate version of an executable (32 or 64-bit) for the user's OS.`), the nicest way might be just to ask the user which version to download.

I'm not sure how you'd do that in elisp though

Comment: Using completing-read would be one way.

Answer (score 0):

Why would you want to now that?

You should be looking at the specific Emacs property/capability and not the hardware attributes.

E.g., [`most-positive-fixnum`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Integer-Basics.html) will tell you the size of the `fixnum` (incidentally, it will also tell you the word size: if it is bugger than 2^32, then you have a 64-bit CPU).

Comment: Calling out to external programs is probably a good enough reason

Comment: what external program depends on that but cannot determine it itself?

Comment: Choosing which program to call perhaps? Not everyone writes nice software - some people distributes different binaries under different names depending on 32/64 bit (see e.g. sqldeveloper)

Comment: "Why would you want to know that?" I wanted to write an Elisp script that would download and run the appropriate version of an executable (32 or 64-bit) for the user's OS.

Comment: 64-bit Emacs cannot load 32-bit `dll`.